# iOS cordova app not seeing images saved with cordova.plugin.file after app update

Tags: ios, file, cordova, path

iOS Cordova application does not see locally saved images after app update. Before that everything works fine. How do i set dynamically relative url with cordova.plugin.file?

I used in config.xml:

```
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

The cordova.plugin.file saves data to:

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory;
```

But after app update they disappear from the folder i see them in in console. I read about ios copying files after update and that i have to set relative path to the images that i save locally from camera. But i do not know how to do it for ios to see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing was that I saved them to a temp directory, which is cleared by ios on app update. After I started saving the images to the Documents/ directory, everything started working fine.

See docs here [https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Comment: I still get the same issue with the cordova.file.documentsDirectory after every app update it updates the directory path

Comment: How about dataDirectory?